# ARM assembly, Branching for correcting values

Tags: assembly, arm, branch

I am writing this code to take a 16 entered temperature values, correct them accordingly, summing and then taking an average.
for example if the value is between (0-20) add +0. If the value is between (21-39) add +1 .. etc. After a the 16th value it goes out of the loop and averages the values.
This is what I got so far but apparently its not working.

```
.text
.global _start
_start:

.equ NUM, 16

LDR R1, =Fahrenheit_Rough               @Load pointer to the Loaded values (Manually entered)
LDR R2, =Fahrenheit_True                @Load pointer to the corrected Values
LDR R3, =Round_Average                  @Load pointer to the Round_Average
MOV R4, #NUM                            @counter for going over 16 values
MOV R5, #0                              @Summing the corrected values, and then getting average

READING:
LDRB R6, [R1], #1                       @Load Temperaure value to R6, increment position by 1
CMP R6, #21                             @Compare first value to 21
ADDMI R6, R6, #0                        @IF less than 21, add +0
BMI COMPUTING                           @jump to Compuing to add the corrected value to the True array and sum avarage

CMP R6, #40                             @Compare second value to 40
ADDMI R6, R6, #1                        @if less than 40 add +1
BMI COMPUTING                           @Jump to computing to add to the corrected value to True array and update average

CMP R6, #60
ADDMI R6, R6, #3
BMI COMPUTING

CMP R6, #80
ADDMI R6, R6, #7
BMI COMPUTING

CMP R6, #100
ADDMI R6, R6, #12
BMI COMPUTING

CMP R6, #121
ADDMI R6, R6, #20
BMI COMPUTING

COMPUTING:
STRB R6, [R2], #1                       @Store the corrected value to the True array. increment by 1
ADD R5,R5,R6                            @Add the corrected value to average
SUBS R4, #1                             @Substract 1 from the ounter
BNE READING                             @If counter not zero, go back to READING
NOP

MOVS R5,R5,LSR #4                       @Shift 4 bit to the right to divide by 16
ADC R5,R5, #1                           @add one if there's a carry


.data
Fahrenheit_Rough:   .byte 0,15,20,25,40,55,65,79,80,85,95,99,102,110,120,121
Fahrenheit_True:    .byte 0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0
Round_Average:      .byte 0x0
.END
```

Comment: Define "not working". Also, use a debugger.

Comment: PS: you don't seem to have an ending.

Comment: pardon me I am new to ARM and trying to find my way around it. I believe after taking in the 16th value, R4 will go to 0 and it'll exit the loop and go to averaging.

Comment: Do you have such sharp "steps" in corrections intentionally, or it's your compromise to not code too many branches, but you would actually like to have linear progression of correction? BTW it's not *apparent* to me, as I did ARM assembly years ago and forgot almost everything, and you didn't describe what's wrong about it. From a quick look it looks ok, after last `ADC` the `R5` may contain average... (but you have to put breakpoint there, as the CPU will continue further into whatever happens to be in memory after that last instruction, and execute it as garbage code).